# why android lollipop modifies my styles?

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I have app and work with this configuration.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
```

In kitkat work fine but in lollipop not respect all styles.
For example

**Kitkat** / **Lollipop**

[image: Kitkat -- > Lollipop]

how i can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, those `Components` are working on +21 API (with shadows or ripples)
I mean, it's working, but not with those beautiful styles.

Refer to following question:

[Material Design and appcompat not working on older API versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817364/material-design-and-appcompat-not-working-on-older-api-versions)

And for getting what you exactly expect with both `Kitkat` and `Lollipop` or -, i'd rather to use `Material Design Libraries` for those Shadows or ripples.

And that makes for different APIs like `Kitkat` and `Lollipop` sense.

hope that helps.